# Azure Load Balacing one Public Port to many internal ports on other machines

Tags: windows, azure, cloud

I am curious if it is possible to load balanced a VM public port, 3000 to many internal machine ports.  I.E:
https://test.cloudservice.com:3000 to:

az-test-01a:3000
az-test-01a:3001
az-test-01a:3002
az-test-01a:3003

az-test-01b:3000
az-test-01b:3001
az-test-01b:3002
az-test-01b:3003

Answer (score 2):

No.

[Load Balanced Set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn655055.aspx) only Load Balance same Public and Same Private ports across **different** VMs. The above described scenario is not possible today (2015-03-19) and with the current state of Azure Infrastructure Services.

While I can to some degree understand this requirement, it is not supported today.